# How would I add this code to a single Wordpress page?

Tags: css, javascript, html

[image]I would like to add this code to a single wordpress page. Have tried to use the plugin 'code embed' but couldn't get it to work properly. I have attached the code to the Fiddle as there is quite a bit. The above image shows the outcome when i either add a shortcode using a plugin or paste the code int the text editor in wordpress. Any help greatly appreciated.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yLqwthyr/1/

Comment: In Wordpress, you can create shortcode to  add this codes inside the content https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API  or you can manually by using this conditional function `is_page('your-page-id')` .

Comment: The above is correct. A lazier option would be to copy the code (HTML and JS) and the CSS into the text view of your single specific page....

Comment: Tried a few different options and when i put it straight into the text editor it messes up the css and js

Answer (score 0):

```
function bettingModuleFunction(){
    // your content
};
add_shortcode( 'print_betting_module', 'bettingModuleFunction' );
```

Put this in your functions.php and you can call the content using [print_betting_module] shortcode.

If you need to call this shortcode inside a file use:

```
echo do_shortcode('[print_betting_module]');
```

If you need to use your shortcode inside widgets put this in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```